# PrestaShop starter theme deprecated?

Tags: themes, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

The PrestaShop [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/themes/getting-started/starter-theme/) instructs developers to create custom themes from the [starter theme](https://github.com/PrestaShop/StarterTheme). The README in the starter theme repository however now has a note that the repository is [deprecated](https://github.com/PrestaShop/StarterTheme/commit/5222429155350928d5532e4bf044758137bbaf29). What is now the recommended way to create new themes? One of the starter theme's goal was to not impose that themes depend on Bootstrap. Where does the project now stand on that front? Should themes be built on top of Bootstrap?

Comment: In the real world create a new theme is more easy and fast start from the **classic** than **starter**, maybe that's the reason why has been deprecated. If you need create your theme using the **_dev** you can take it from the master dev repo.

Comment: This is so silly that they killed the starter theme just right after introducing it, and it suposed to be better than overriding the classic theme...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at classic-rocket:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/classic-rocket

And, yes you are right the documentation is not up to date, thanks for the reminder. I add that to my todo list.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is searching a Starter Theme for Prestashop in 2021, I just found a newer starter theme with Bootstrap 4.6 (classic-rocket uses 4.4) and a lot of tools up to date: https://github.com/Oksydan/modern-prestashop-starter-theme